# NodeJS cannot read property of JSON which does exist?

Tags: json, node.js, express, request, undefined

I'm having a sudden an unexpected issue with a piece of code which has been working correctly for weeks.

In the following request and (part of) the response:

```
//request 
let campaignRes = request('POST', reqUrl, campaignOptions);

//body of response
{"type":"Buffer","data":[ //some integer values ]}
```

You can see that the "data" field clearly exists, and I have been able to access it in the following ways for several weeks now:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(campaignRes.body));
let campaignData = JSON.parse(campaignRes.getBody('utf8')).body.data;
```

However, this now produces the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
at Object.MongoClient.connect.MongoClient.connect [as generateReport] (/mtpath/reports.js:31:68)
at Object.<anonymous> (/mypath/test.js:7:22)
at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
at startup (node.js:146:18)
at node.js:404:3
```

I am somewhat at a loss at to why this error occurs now and not earlier.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

UPDATE:

```
    let campaignData = campaignRes.body.data;
```

Does not fare any better.

Comment: Show us the value of `campaignRes.getBody('utf8')`. Why do you think the result contains `body`? Besides, you should always check the value returned by `JSON.parse`. Try this: `var parsedJson = JSON.parse(campaignRes.getBody('utf8')); console.log(parsedJson ? parsedJson.data : '(failed to parse JSON)');`

Comment: Thank you! You are exactly right, the difference between previously and now is that there is no `body` because there is now an error!

Seems that someone may have changed the password on this account.

Answer (score 0):

As indirectly determined by Rusian Osmanov above, the problem was simply that there is no `body` on this response. The reason this worked correctly in prior works is that there was a `body` then, but no longer is now (due to some credentials being changed, I now get an error response on this request).

Thanks!